# Have trouble understanding nested scope in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I got confused when reading the article from this site (pitfall #5):

http://thenittygritty.co/angularjs-pitfalls-using-scopes

http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html

My question is:

1. is this scenario pretty much like two variables with the same name in plain js, one defined locally (e.g. within a nested function) and one defined globally (e.g. windows.onload), so the local one always override the global one?
2. I kinda understand that $scope.variable should reference a model which contains values but it doesn't really impact the outcome if they have the same name regardless of having the dot syntax. I don't understand if putting a "." dot would result in a difference in the OUTPUT VALUE above. For example, replacing them with {{user.name}}. How does this best practice work?

The following code from the site is trying to demostrate if the 2nd {{username}} changes, the 1st {{username}} will not change.

Html:

```
<span>Outside Controller: Your name is: {{username}}</span>
<div ng-controller="SignupController">
    <span>Inside Controller: Your name is: {{username}}</span>
    <fieldset legend="User details">
    <input ng-model="username" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('SignupController', function($scope){});
```

Comment: There is still no better explanation of the scope inheritance concept that this wiki https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like prototypal inheritance in JavaScript.

```
function Jedi(){}
Jedi.prototype.name = 'Luke';
```

Now, if you do this:

```
var obiwan = new Jedi();
console.log(obiwan.name); //Luke
```

However if I do this:

```
var obiwan = new Jedi();
obiwan.name = 'Obi-wan';
console.log(obiwan.name); //Obi-wan

var luke= new Jedi();
console.log(luke.name); //Luke
```

This is the way JavaScript resolve properties. When reading a property,  it first look it up in the object, if not found, it looks it up in its prototype, if not found it looks it up in its prototype's prototype and so on, until it reaches the top of the prototype chain (if not found).

However, when writing a property, if the object does not already have the given field, it is created and from that moment on, as per the search criteria explained above, the value that you get when reading is that directly in the object, and not in its prototype.

A solution suggested in angular is to store model data not directly as fields in the scope, but as objects, to avoid this behavior. For instance:

```
function Jedi()
Jedi.protype.data = {name: 'Luke'};

var obiwan = new Jedi();
obiwan.data.name = 'Obi-wan';

var luke= new Jedi();
console.log(luke.data.name); //Obi-wan
```

This time the field under prototypal inheritance is `data`, and so all objects share it.

Comment: I am starting to get a connection between your example and Angularjs scope inheritance. Strangely I missed to cover your example when learning Js Oop, that you cannot change it if they are primitive values however it is possible when prototype property is an object. I guess the only reason you can change the prototypal property is only because .data is pointing to an object (i.e. a reference stored on the stack)?

Comment: The book [Professional JavaScript for Web Developers](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-JavaScript-Developers-Nicholas-Zakas/dp/1118026691/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1391168315&sr=8-1&keywords=professional+javascript+for+web+developers) have the best explanations I have ever read on the subject. See if you can get a copy. And yes, in my last example both objects share a reference to the same `data` instance, most likely in the heap memory area (unlikely in the stack).

Comment: Ur right on Heap. Typo from my last comment. Angular scope makes sense because of this now. Thanks.